# how to solve the problem if i use pyAudioAnalysis to do regression analysis on wav file?

Tags: pyaudioanalysis

I use the command

```
python .\audioAnalysis.py regressionFile -i E:\test\20160302.wav --model svm --regression data/svmSpeechEmotion
```

and here is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Download\pyAudioAnalysis-master\pyAudioAnalysis\audioAnalysis.py", line 603, in <module>
  File "D:\Download\pyAudioAnalysis-master\pyAudioAnalysis\audioAnalysis.py", line 120, in regressionFileWrapper
    R, regressionNames = aT.file_regression(inputFile, model_name, model_type)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Download\pyAudioAnalysis-master\pyAudioAnalysis\audioTrainTest.py", line 1121, in file_regression
    = load_model(regression_models[0], True)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

now i don't know what can i do.